# Are all measures Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

In our lecture we ran out of time, so our prof told us a few properties about measure: He said that a measure is $\sigma$-additive iff it has a right-side continuous function that it creates. And he was not only referring to probability measures. 
After going through my lecture notes, I thought that this would imply that there can be no other measures than ones having a right-side continuous function (I think they are called Lebesgue-Stieltjes measures) as $\sigma$-additivity is a prerequisite to be a measure. So somehow, this does not fit together. Does anybody know what he could have meant here? Or was he only referring to probability measures?

Is anything unclear about my question?

Comment: What is the function that a measure "creates?"

Comment: I think he is talking about the function $F$ in this reference http://mathprelims.wordpress.com/2008/10/27/the-lebesgue-stieltjes-measure/

Comment: indeed, this is what i meant

Comment: A cumulative distribution function (CDF) is what we call $F$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many other measures. For example, the counting measure: $\mu(A)$ is the number of elements of $A$, with $\mu(A)=\infty$ if $A$ is infinite. This is not a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure. Neither are the [Hausdorff measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure) $\mathcal H^d$ with $0<d<1$. Indeed, all of these measures have $\mu([a,b])=\infty$ whenever $a<b$, which is something a Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure cannot satisfy.

A Borel measure on $\mathbb R$ is a [Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integration) if and only if it is [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Borel_measure); equivalently, if it is finite on bounded sets. See *Real Analysis* by Royden, section 12.3.

---

Additional remark from comments: if $\mu$ is   a  *finitely additive measure* that is finite on bounded sets, then the $\sigma$-additivity of $\mu$ is equivalent to  its CDF being right-continuous. One direction is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/679172/), the other direction is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668513/).

Comment: so would the statement: a measure is sigma-additive iff it has a right-side continuous CDF be at least true for probability measures?

Comment: you are right, I am not very precise, sorry. I mean if you have a map from some subset of the real numbers with the appropriate borel sigma algebra that fulfills all the properties that a probability measure fulfills besides the sigma- additivity. Is it then correct to say: This map fulfills sigma-addivity iff it has a right-side continuous CDF? The thing is: I want to figure out what my prof could have meant with his dubious remarks..

Answer (score 2):

**The statement is certainly wrong by consistency:**

Right-side continuous functions are defined/only make sense for functions whos domain is the real line (actually a right-closed subset of the real line).
Thus it gives rise at most for measures over the reals (or over a right-closed subset of the reals).

However, when restricting to measures over the reals the statement remains still wrong as pointed out above.

Besides, depending on the range this yields a real measure or more generally a vector measure...

Comment: yes correct, we need to talk about the real line, but is the statement: a measure is sigma-additive iff it has a right-side continuous CDF at least true for probability measures?

Comment: What means CDF?

Comment: Note also, probabilty measures make sense on *any* domain...

Comment: CDF =cumulative distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the Dirac measure.

$$\delta_a(E)= 1\text{ if }a\in E, 0\text{ otherwise}$$

Or what about the measure that is zero on the empty set and infinity otherwise.

Comment: The Dirac measure is no exception to the rule that there is a right-continuous function (in this case the Heaviside step function) meeting the desiderata.